# Auto suggest TextBox from mysql database column in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a HTML text box and I want it to auto complete the textbox from the values in a mysql array.

```
Supplier:
      <input type="text" name="supplier" id="supplier" autocomplete="off" required style="position:absolute; left:200px" />
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db("purchasing", $con);
$array=mysql_query("SELECT `supplier` FROM  existing_material");
```

Comment: Search it on google, there are lots of code available.

Comment: I did, There are lot of codes for VB but not for php.

Comment: change `VB` to `PHP` while searching in the search term. it will show up the results.

Comment: http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/jquery-php-mysql-ajax-autocomplete/ http://www.amitpatil.me/php-ajax-autosuggest-jquery-plugin/ http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using html5

```
        <input name="frameworks" list="frameworks" />

        <datalist id="frameworks">
             <?php 
                $query = "";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
             ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['yourfeild']; ?>">
            <?php } ?>            
        </datalist>
```

example code:

```
    <input name="frameworks" list="frameworks" />

    <datalist id="frameworks">
        <option value="MooTools">
        <option value="Moobile">
        <option value="Dojo Toolkit">
        <option value="jQuery">
        <option value="YUI">
    </datalist>
```